# How can I pause a tick event assigned to a DisplayObject in createjs?

Tags: html, canvas, createjs

I added an EventListener for the "tick" event of a DisplayObject:

```
that.timerListener = that.timer.on("tick", timerTicker, null, false);
```

I can disable that event by calling:

```
that.timer.removeAllEventListeners("tick");
```

But how can I pause it? In the createjs documentation they only add tick events like this:

```
 createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
 createjs.Ticker.paused = true;
```

But "that.timerListener.paused = true;" is not working because its not a Ticker class..

Any ideas?

Comment: Just let the ticker run and in the tick function just exit at top of the function if you are in a pause state. `function handleTick(){ if(createjs.Ticker.paused){ return; }...`

Comment: Note that `removeAllEventListeners` does not take a parameter. You are removing all the event listeners, not just "tick" ones.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. In the createjs documentation it says you can add a parameter if you only want to remove the listeners of the specified type: http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Ticker.html#method_removeAllEventListeners